# Can we use "to be stripped" instead of "being stripped" in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, gerunds, infinitives, infinitive-vs-gerund

The warning from the European commission could lead to that country being stripped  of its European rights.

(As far as l know we must use infinitive after nouns )

Comment: As a learner: present participle can be used as the object complement, and that's the case here.

Comment: @Cardinal you're right about the choice. But I am afraid I've understood your explanation. Because on top of my head *lead* in this meaning licences a complement - a Preposition Phrase headed by *to*. There generally is no other complement.

Comment: Take that road. It could lead home.

Comment: I deliberately copied  it because l haven't had a correct answer

Comment: You are always welcome to follow up your questions on the ELL's main chatroom: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24938/language-overflow

Answer (score 1):

At least in American English, only the -ing version is natural in this particular expression.

What do you mean by *after a noun?*

> Mary loves cake

has an inflected verb, not an infinitive, after a noun.

Comment: I mean Country for another example "In Britain, you will have a chance to improve your English."

Answer (score -1):

The sentence can be rephrased to use "to be stripped":

> The warning from the European commission could lead that country to be stripped of its European rights.

Answer (score -1):

I'm just an English student but I think it means the country in question could lose her European rights as a result of the European commission's warning.

Comment: Hello Itamar, I am afraid that the question does not ask for the meaning. You may want to edit your current answer to include that.

Comment: And change 'loose' to 'lose'.

Comment: Hi, thanks Michael. I just made the edit. I can understand his question now, you are right. I'll keep my answer that anyway... maybe it can help someone. Thanks again.